# "if else statement" when no $_REQUEST exist

Tags: php, request, if-statement

I am making a simple if and else statement to get value from a requested link my code is

```
if($_REQUEST['f_id']=='')
{
    $friend_id=0;
}
else
{
    $friend_id=$_REQUEST['f_id'];
}
```

and suppose the link is `www.example.com/profile.php?f_id=3`

now its simple as if the `f_id` is empty or with value either of the above if and else statement would run. but what is a user is just playing around with link and he removes the whole `?f_id=3` with link left to be opened with `www.example.com/profile.php` then how to detect that `f_id` dosen't exist and in that case redirect to a error page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the isset() php function to test that:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST) || $_REQUEST['f_id']=='')
{ 
   $friend_id=0; 
} 
else 
{ 
  $friend_id=$_REQUEST['f_id']; 
}
```

Comment: See my comment on Zoltan's answer.

Comment: i think there should be a || instead of &&

Comment: he want to restrict the condition, therefore I wrote && instead of ||

Comment: `if(!isset($_REQUEST['f_id']) || $_REQUEST['f_id']=='')` worked for me

Comment: Much easier to use `if (empty($_REQUEST['f_id']))`

Answer (score 6):

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['f_id'] ) ) {
    if($_REQUEST['f_id']=='') {
        $friend_id=0;
    } else {
        $friend_id=$_REQUEST['f_id'];
    }
} else {
    REDIRECT TO ERROR PAGE
}
```

**UPDATE** Since your URLS-s look like `www.example.com/profile.php?f_id=3` you should use `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Before I upvote, I'd like to see some mentioning about not use REQUEST variables but instead using POST and GET.

Comment: this worked for me `if(!isset($_REQUEST['f_id']) || $_REQUEST['f_id']=='')`

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but here's an "elegant" solution that I always use.  I start with this code for all the variables I'm interested in and go from there.  There are a number of other things you can do with the extracted variables as well shown in the PHP [EXTRACT](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.extract.php) documentation.

```
// Set the variables that I'm allowing in the script (and optionally their defaults)
    $f_id = null        // Default if not supplied, will be null if not in querystring
    //$f_id = 0         // Default if not supplied, will be false if not in querystring
    //$f_id = 'NotFound'    // Default if not supplied, will be 'NotFound' if not in querystring

// Choose where the variable is coming from
    extract($_REQUEST, EXTR_IF_EXISTS); // Data from GET or POST
    //extract($_GET, EXTR_IF_EXISTS);   // Data must be in GET
    //extract($_POST, EXTR_IF_EXISTS);  // Data must be in POST

if(!$f_id) {
    die("f_id not supplied...do redirect here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [empty](https://www.php.net/empty) to combine the 2x isset into 1 statement (unless you actually have a friend_id of 0 which would result in empty being true)

```
if(empty($_REQUEST['f_id'])) {
   $friend_id=0;
} else {
  $friend_id=$_REQUEST['f_id'];
}
```